Variables Calculator Bison and flex
How can i Write a LEX and Bison Program to recognize a valid arithmetic expression that uses operators +, -, * and /and It gives priority to parentheses () and Accepts definition of variables and this variables can include the previous expressions and operations?
m=5
y=9+5


Read a compiler textbook, they should have a section on parsing with operator precedence.

This question is a bit open-ended to fully answer. In brief, you will need Bison rules for an expression that looks something like:
varassign : VARIABLE '=' exp
    ;

exp : '(' exp ')'
    | exp '+' exp
    | exp '-' exp
    | '-' exp
    | NUMBER
    ;

You will need to specify the precedence of operators. Refer to the Bison Manual section Specifying Operator Precedence for details.
For lex, you just need to return the single-character tokens, and have a rule that parses [0-9]+ as a NUMBER token. And presumably you return any non-keyword string of letters as VARIABLE.

Thank you  I am kind a new in this thing
